# Compiler Optimization of copy construction?

Tags: c++, optimization, copy-constructor

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    A(int a) { cout << "cast "; }
    A(const A& a) { cout << "copy " ;}
};

int main () {
    int x = 0;
    A a = x;
    return 0;
}
```

gives the output `cast`, while I expected the output to be: `cast copy`.
Is it a compiler optimization, or a simple misunderstanding of what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's compiler optimization.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to elide a copy here, although these must be an accessible copy constructor. This is an optimization that is allowed to break the "as-if" rule. See [this GoTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm).

Comment: Read about [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: That's what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `"cast"` should be `"convert"`. The code here has no casts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An  implicit conversion from `int` to `A`  through the constructor `A(int i)` is happening over here.

So, I guess, compiler does some optimization.

If you use `explicit` keyword for first constructor, it won't compile.